# Remove node from graph during traversal

Tags: java, jgrapht

I am trying to delete a node/set of nodes from a defined graph (org.jgrapht.Graph) before doing a Topological traversal on it.

Sample graph definition

```
        Graph<URI, DefaultEdge> g = new DefaultDirectedGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);

        URI google = new URI("http://www.google.com");
        URI wikipedia = new URI("http://www.wikipedia.org");
        URI jgrapht = new URI("http://www.jgrapht.org");

        // add the vertices
        g.addVertex(google);
        g.addVertex(wikipedia);
        g.addVertex(jgrapht);

        // add edges to create linking structure
        g.addEdge(jgrapht, wikipedia);
        g.addEdge(google, jgrapht);
        g.addEdge(google, wikipedia);
        g.addEdge(wikipedia, google);
```

How can we remove specific nodes, say `wikipedia` (and its childs, if any) from this tree?

I have tried different traversals available in [jgrapht library](https://jgrapht.org/guide/UserOverview#graph-traversal), however all of them explicitly mentions that graph shouldn't be modified during traversal.
Traversals tried: DepthFirst, RandomWalk, BreadthFirst, ClosestFirst, TopologicalOrder.

Is there any way I can delete nodes with/without traversal from the graph in optimal way?

Comment: Pleaes post a complete example. Your title says that you want to delete a node during a traversal, your text states that you want to delete before your traversal. To remove a node from the graph before traversal, simply invoke `removeVertex(V v)`: https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/Graph.html#removeVertex-V-

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using `BFS`:

1. Create a ´Set´ for storing edges.
2. Say you want to remove `b` from `a -> b -> c`, then you should mark edges from `a` -> `b` and `b -> c` as to be deleted (basically adding them to the set).
3. After you finish the `BFS` you will have set of edges to be deleted, delete them and the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using BFS. Traverse the graph using a dequeue, and if the child of a vertex is the node to be deleted set child of current vertex to null. This will ensure that when a topological sort is run on the graph that the node to be deleted (and any of its children) will never be reached. Running this BFS will take O(ElogV) time.